# How to give different weights to features while training a SGDClassifier in Scikit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

From the documentation,

```
class sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(class_weight=None)
```

Like the class_weight function, how do I give weights to particular aspects of my feature set? Like my feature sets consists of raw text, and some name. While training I want to give more weight to name, and less weight to the raw text. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to give weights to features in `SGDClassifier`, and as far I know in no other learner in scikit-learn.

In general, it does not make sense to give different weights to features. After all, you do machine learning because you want the computer to figure out which features are more important. If *name* is more important than *raw text* the classifier will figure that out internally.

Now, if you still want to have different features with different importance you can combine multiple classifiers:
Train one classifier using only the *name* feature, and train another classifier using only *raw text* features. Then combine their output by taking the weighted average of each classifier's output. You can give the *name*-classifier a higher weight, which will increase *name*'s impact on the combined output.